# When Facebook removes an App, it puts the site's domain on a blacklist?

Tags: facebook, oauth-2.0, facebook-apps, facebook-oauth, facebook-access-token

I got my app removed by Facebook last week.

Now I'm trying to build a new one correcting the problems, but I always get an error authenticating the user.

> SECURITY WARNING: Sharing the above URL with anyone is the same as
>   sharing your Facebook password with them - it will give them access to
>   your Facebook account. Despite what you may have been promised, you
>   will not receive cash, a gift card, or free airline tickets in
>   exchange for this URL.

I'm calling the API this way:

```
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?
client_id=MY_APP_ID
&display=popup
&redirect_uri=http://www.my-url.com/823/
&scope=user_about_me
```

My Facebok app config is:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/s9WSW.png

I'm trying to use the same domain used in that removed app.
Does Facebook has a domain blacklist? I can't create a new app with that domain anymore (in the example "www.my-url.com/823/")? 
Or am I just missing something in the settings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes , they probably block all the information related to your App and website.

Comment: But when I received the email saying that they blocked my app, it says:
"... However, if you'd like to launch a new version of your app with a new app ID and canvas URL, please first make adjustments to ensure you're providing a good user experience and meeting our policies.". So the developer can build a new app, but they didn't say about using the same domain...

Comment: That's true because it's just like a warning. and they give you a chance to create another application. but for the information that had been used in the App ...would be recorded by them. 
I think you should try a different website to make sure the problem doesn't related to your webdeveloper account...

Comment: The problem was that my app was removed by Facebook. When this happens, Facebook puts the site domain in a black list.
The solution was to redirect to the canvas page.